# How to use ajax for saving image with php

Tags: php, ajax, image, file, webcam

I'm trying to use ajax for calling to another php page, which saving an image taken from webcam.
While I'm using the following code I didn't get any error but instead of saving the image it's saves an empty image (white).

The ajax code:

```
function ajaxPOSTTest() {
        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxPOSTTestRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxPOSTTestRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxPOSTTestRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        ajaxPOSTTestRequest.onreadystatechange = ajaxCalled_POSTTest;
        var url = "storeImage.php";
        var params = "image="+srcI;
        ajaxPOSTTestRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxPOSTTestRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxPOSTTestRequest.send(params);
    }

    //Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    function ajaxCalled_POSTTest() {
        if (ajaxPOSTTestRequest.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("snapshot").innerHTML = ajaxPOSTTestRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
```

**when srcI is the src of the image and storeImage.php is the php page which the ajax send the information to.

The php code:

```
<?php

    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $folderPath = "upload/";

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName =  'camera_installation.png';

    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    print $img;

?>
```

When I debug it, the php return the src of the image so the ajax does work but the image still saved as blank.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the way you receive the image in php, $img = $_POST['image'];, i dont think it's right, try $file = $_FILES['image'];, then for the file name just say $fileName = $file['name'];

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The image is taken from a webcam and not from an uploaded file.